# Passing distinct Multiple Parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, distinct

I'm in a peculiar situation here. I have a report which takes `@ProjectID` as a parameter and shows all the info related to that project.

Now I have to pass multiple project ids separately as parameters to the report and each `report(ProjectID)` should show in a distinct page.

I did research on `Multivalues` parameters but could not find a way to accomplish this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the @ProjectId parameter as multivalue

In your SQL query use the multivalue parameter using IN eg. `WHERE ProjectId IN (@ProjectId)`

Add a table group, grouping on ProjectId field. In the group settings enable "Page break at end"